# Swift - Animating UIView.frame width/height that loads a Custom Class XIB with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, xcode8

So I'm pretty new to Swift/Xcode and have been running into this issue:

My main view is a list of UIView's loaded into a UIScrollView. Each of those UIView's is using a custom XIB class that has it's own UIScrollView and content. Tapping on one of the views in the list expands it's frame to the screen's width/height and centers it. The problem is that the scrollable area does not expand with it. Wherever the UIView is when it's tapped is the only area that's scrollable when it expands.

[Here's a visual example of where the scroll area is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC8BH.png)

When the view is tapped, I'm expanding it's frame

```
self.testPack.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.packScroll.contentOffset.y, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
```

[This is what the main layout looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drri8.png)

Any idea why the scroll area doesn't expand with it?

Comment: If I understood correctly you should also set the `contentSize` property of a scroll view when you expand a view that contains it.

Comment: @LëshaTurkowski Do you mean the scrollview inside the XIB? I've tried this and it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Updated the post to also include an image of what the main layout looks like. Each view inside the ScrollView loads a XIB with a height of about 1200. So ideally scrolling is enabled for those when they're expanded to fullscreen.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I just figured out that it has something to do with the view underneath in the list blocking scrolling somehow. I'm currently trying to do this but it's not helping `self.view.bringSubview(toFront: testPack)`
  `self.testPack.layer.zPosition = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude`